# RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key does not work in .NET Core

Tags: .net, .net-core, x509certificate2

I have an assembly compiled with .NET Framework 2.0 (yes, pretty old stuff) which performs encryption with a certificate's public key. The code is extremely simple:

```
X509Certificate2 objCert = new X509Certificate2(path);
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)objCert.PublicKey.Key;
byte [] EncrRes = rsa.Encrypt(data, false);
```

This continues to work with all recent versions of .NET Framework, but refuses to work under .NET Core. I got two different but similar error messages.

Windows 10:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng' to type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider'.

Linux:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSAOpenSsl' to type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider'.

Is there a way to code this simple operation so that it would work on both .NET Framework 2.0+ and .NET core?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In .NET Core, `X509Certificate2.PublicKey.Key` and `X509Certificate2.PrivateKey` use platform-specific implementation of key. On Windows, there are two implementations, legacy `RSACryptoServiceProvider` and modern `RSACng`.

You have to change the way how you access these properties. And do not access them. Instead, use extension methods: [X509Certificate2 Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?view=netframework-4.8#extension-methods). They return safe abstract classes you shall use. Do not try to use explicit cast to anything. For `RSA` keys use `RSA` class and so on.

```
X509Certificate2 objCert = new X509Certificate2(path);
// well, it is reasonable to check the algorithm of public key. If it is ECC,
// then call objCert.GetECDsaPublicKey()
RSA rsa = objCert.GetRsaPublicKey();
byte [] EncrRes = rsa.Encrypt(data, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but GetRsaPublicKey is not available in .NET 2.0. I already found and posted a solution below.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out on my own. Instead of

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)objCert.PublicKey.Key;
```

do

```
RSA rsa_helper = (RSA)objCert.PublicKey.Key;
RSAParameters certparams = rsa_helper.ExportParameters(false);
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
RSAParameters paramcopy = new RSAParameters();
paramcopy.Exponent = certparams.Exponent;
paramcopy.Modulus = certparams.Modulus;
rsa.ImportParameters(paramcopy);
```

Works with .NET 2.0+ and .NET Core!

Comment: Why you need that old `RSACryptoServiceProvider`? Its use is really discouraged. Find right methods in my other response.

Comment: For backwards compatibility.

Comment: .NET Core isn't backward compatible with .NET 2.0.

Comment: A component written for .NET 2.0 can be used with .NET Core, though, if properly coded.

Comment: With this approach you are sticking to Windows only and don't get any benefits from .NET Core cross-platform. Your code won't run on Linux or Mac, because there is no such `RSACryptoServiceProvider` class.